# error happend when i pull image from my harbor

Tags: docker, harbor

I can `docker login` my harbor
[enter image description here][1]

also i created `daemon.json` like
[enter image description here][2]

so here i will show how my harbor hub looklike
[enter image description here][3]

Then when i want to pull image like this one;
[enter image description here][4]

use this command `docker pull tcregistry.starcloud.io/test/owncloud:latest`,it feedbacked error;
[enter image description here][5]

I am using harborv1.1.2,i want to migrate all image to a new version harbor.but now i can't pull it on my machine
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0iJi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEF6s.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qshXZ.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GTLG.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JT0.png

Comment: i don't know if i explan my question,or how i can find out what's going on with it.

Comment: i use the copy function on harbor v1.1.2 but have the same problem 403,